# bash: run a script with set -e (errexit)

Tags: bash

Is there a way to run a bash script with `set -e`, i.e., as if `set -e` were in the first line of the script? I know there is for example `bash -x` to emulate `set -x`, but I didn't see anything to emulate `set -e`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`bash` can use any of the options that are valid with `set` as a command line option, so you can simply use

```
bash -e myScript
```

Here's the first sentence from the Options section of the man page (emphasis mine; I know I glossed over this sentence for a long time as well):

> In addition to the single-character shell options **documented in the description of the set builtin command**, bash interprets the following options when it is invoked:

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
(set -e; . file.sh)
```